# Edge profile preference - Automatic sign in with Work or School account

Tags: single-sign-on, intune

Struggling with what should be a simple setting that I'm obviously missing.

I'm in the process of setting up Intune but noticed that these new AAD-joined devices seemingly aren't recognising the signed-in account for MS sites e.g. portal.office.com

I had enabled Azure AD Seamless Single Sign-on for our domain-joined devices to improve user experience (also added the BlockAADWorkplaceJoin reg entry so users didn't receive the additional prompt to manage device) but not sure how to get this same behaviour with Intune.

There are a few settings I've already configured for Edge including hide first run and force sync but I believe I need to toggle-on "Automatically sign in to sites with your current work or school account?". The 2 options which look related have no effect (Allow single sign-on for Microsoft sites using this profile & Single sign-on for work or school sites using this profile enabled).

TIA,

JB.